# AngularFire $requireAuth not detecting expired authentication

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

Upon my googling for this issue, I found [the following](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/590) leading me to believe that it shouldn't be an issue so I'm sure I am doing something wrong but just can't work it out.

Occasionally when I navigate to my app after my authentication has expired, it will load the page instead of redirecting to /login and in the console I see the:

```
Error: permision denied at /the/firebase/url: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data
```

If I do a reload of the page I will successfully get directed to /login as expected.

```
angular.module('app',['firebase','ngRoute','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap'])
    .factory("Auth",function($firebaseAuth){
        var ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com");
        return $firebaseAuth(ref);
    })
    .run(['$rootScope','$location','$window',function($rootScope,$location,$window){
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError',function(event,next,previous,error){
            $location.path('/login');
        });

        if($window.localStorage.getItem('app-last-list')) {
            $location.path('/lists/' + $window.localStorage.getItem('app-last-list'));
        }

    }])
    .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',{
                templateUrl: 'views/list-view.html',
                controller: 'ListViewController',
                resolve: {
                    "currentAuth": ['Auth', function(Auth) {
                        return Auth.$requireAuth();
                    }]
                }
            })
            .when('/login',{
                templateUrl: 'views/login-view.html',
                controller: 'LoginController'
            })
            .when('/lists/:id', {
                templateUrl: 'views/list-items-view.html',
                controller: 'ListItemsController',
                resolve: {
                    "currentAuth": ['Auth',function(Auth){
                        return Auth.$requireAuth();
                    }],
                    "list": ['$route','dao',function($route,dao){
                        return dao.getPrivateList($route.current.params.id).$loaded();
                    }],
                    "items": ['$route','dao',function($route,dao){
                        return dao.getListItems($route.current.params.id).$loaded();
                    }]
                }
            })
            .otherwise( {redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);
```

Comment: what version of angularfire do you use ?

Comment: @KeatsPeeks 1.2.0

Comment: Can you turn on debug logging and capture the output during one of the failed events? Sounds like it's probably logging in first, then noticing it's expired, then reverting the login status. Probably, you don't have anything redirecting back to /login if the login state changes after initial load event. Note that the permission denied error isn't surprising; you load the data in parallel to checking login status (the resolve calls aren't sequential afaik); that probably happens every time a user goes to that link without being logged in.

Comment: Debug logging command:  `firebase.database().enableLogging(true);`

Comment: @Kato I have turned on debug logging but I probably won't capture the failure event until the morning after it has been idle for some time. Is there an alternative to the parallel loading + auth check other than unwrapping promises in the controller?

Comment: @Kato sat down at my computer after work and clicked on the tab to see '/' loaded with no data showing and this in the console: http://pastebin.com/5K2XdqWs

Comment: @tony that is weird--can you provide complete version info? I'd like to repro this locally and try to resolve it. I think we need to monitor auth state and kick the user out to the login screen if auth expires. We may need to take some other steps here--need to experiment a bit to see.

Comment: @Kato did you mean like: AngularJS v1.5.8, AngularFire 1.2.0 (Date: 03/28/2016), Firebase v2.4.2, angular-ui-bootstrap v2.0.1 (Date: 2016-08-02) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Are you handling the $routeChangeError event in the run block to tell it to redirect?

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", 
        function(event, current, previous, eventObj) {
            if (eventObj === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
                console.log('auth required!');
                $location.path("/login");
            }
        }
    );
})
```

Comment: Yeah in the code I posted I am just redirecting on any error

Comment: I totally missed that sorry. From the docs and everything online it looks right. Is it pulling the data from the cache?

Comment: Are you referring to local storage? I utilize that to restore state as launching as a standalone web app on iPhone does a fresh load. As for caching, I have been testing out the cache manifest (as I ran into issues with templateUrl's being cached and not being udpated) and it seems to be working pretty good

Comment: I was referring to the browser cache instead of the application cache. Have you set the cache-control in your headers? Also, I noticed that the application cache has been deprecated and removed from the web standards. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Comment: Yeah I had saw that too but hadn't looked into an alternative as of yet. Do you think that is the cause of the problem? Locally I use https://github.com/indexzero/http-server with no cache but I don't control where it's hosted

Comment: That seems to be the only possibility left. Instead of no-cache, have you tried no-store? It prevents anything being stored from the request and forces an http request.

It looks like using the option `-c-1` with http-server is the way to disable caching completely. Doing this would at least get us closer to seeing what's going on.

Comment: I'm currently testing it out locally without the manifest cache and with the `-c-` option on http-server; has to idle for a while to create the failing condition

Comment: Just clicked on the tab of my app and I see the main page loaded without Firebase data and the following in the console: `FIREBASE WARNING: resumeSession() was canceled: Auth token is expired.` and `Error: permission_denied at /the/firebase/url: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.` On a page reload I get directed to /login as expected